# How to trigger code, to process items, before the Application_Quit event?

Tags: vba, events, outlook

I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit
 
Public WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
 
' Initiation
Private Sub Application_Startup()
 
Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
 
End Sub
 
' Termination
Private Sub myOlExp_Close()
 
MsgBox "quit"
   
End Sub
```

The code runs but when the last/main Outlook window is being closed, this event is not triggered.

I have also tried Application_Quit - but when this runs it is no longer possible to process mail items.

**Background:** I am trying to reorganize certain items when I close Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You must subscribe to each `Explorer` instance individually and keep these references alive if you want to get events fired each time.

Basically, you need to maintain the list of `Explorer` objects opened by handling the [NewExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorers.newexplorer) event which is fired whenever a new explorer window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code. In the event handler, you may add a new `Explorer` instance to the collection and remove it in the [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.close(even)) event handler when a corresponding instance is closed.

Comment: Thanks - I will try that and post the results

Comment: I have tried the Explorers_NewExplorer event - this is fired as expected.

However the Close Explorer_Close event is still not triggered.